# 'cancel edit' in angular js using splice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using datagrid using data from listOfAttributes array. there is edit icon, on click on that again two buttons there.. save and cancel edit. I want if user click on cancel edit, updated data should be clear and previously data should again persist. I am using splice for add previous object, and delete current object at a same time but it doesn't work.

```
 $scope.edit = function(attribute) {
    angular.copy(attribute, $scope.copyAttr);
 }

$scope.save = function(attribute){
  // works fine;
}

 $scope.cancelEdit = function(attribute) { // doesn't work

    var indx = $scope.listOfAttributes.indexOf(attribute);

    $scope.listOfAttributes.splice(indx, 0, $scope.copyAttr);
    $scope.listOfAttributes.splice(indx,1);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You insert `copyAttr` at `indx`, and then delete it immediately after in `listOfAttributes`.

```
listOfAttributes = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
listOfAttributes.splice(1, 0, 'D'); // A, D, B, C
listOfAttributes.splice(1, 1);      // A, B, C
```

If you want to replace the item at `indx`, you only need once splice:

```
$scope.listOfAttributes.splice(indx, 1, $scope.copyAttr);
```